# JS Failed to detect childWindow closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a function when a child window closed, but it failed to check to `window.closed`.

Here is my code:

```
<button onclick='openChild(); ></button>

 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            function openChild(){                   
                var child_window = window.open('http://www.website.com','win1','toolbar=0,status=1,location=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=950,height=600');

                if(<?php echo $active?> ==0 ){
            setTimeout(function(child_window ){

                    child_window.close();
               }, 1000);
         }
  child_window.onunload =checkChild; 

  var check_token = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
    }       

 function checkChild() {
if (child_window && child_window.closed) {
    alert("Closed!");   
clearInterval(check_token);     
$.get("check.php", function(data) {});
location.reload();

}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `checkChild()` function the variable `childWindow` does not exist, but because you used `checkChild()` as an event handler you can replace `childWindow` with `this` keyword

```
function openChild(){                 
    var child_window = window.open('http://www.website.com','win1','toolbar=0,status=1,location=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=950,height=600');

    if(<?php echo $active?> ==0 ){
      child_window.close();
    }
    child_window.onunload = function() {
        // this functions fires when closed
        alert('closed');
        $.get("check.php", function(data) {});
        location.reload();
    };
}
```

Comment: hi Edwin . I have replaced this. 
`function checkChild() {
    if (this && this.closed) {` ,another concern is the timer doesnot work also.

Comment: which the `check_token` one if yes why are you doing that?

Comment: I mean the timer does work, but failed to detect the closed window

Comment: If it didn't alert('Closed') its because `this.closed` would be false, because the event handler happens right before the window closes so it's not closed. You would have to take `this.closed` off from if statement

Comment: if I take `this.closed` from if statement then I cannot detect close window . when the child window is closed, no alert popped out

Comment: Yes because right when it closes `checkChild` fires meaning it is closed

Comment: You donot understand. when checkChild fired and the window is closed, it should alert "Closed". but nothing happened.

Comment: Hi Edwin onunload doesnot work in FF "security" . the event is fired right after the window poppped up , not when it is closed.

Comment: go back to the same jsfiddle copy paste your code, and message me